# React reuse reactElement, reactElement state will be reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wanna use react make act system like android activity system

following it's my code, the bug is I have set actE's state k:"v", but final line `app.setState({act: actE})` cause actE state k: null, **why actE state is reset?**

```
    class Act extends PureComponent<any, { k: string }> {
        constructor(props: any, context: any) {
            super(props, context)
            this.state = {
                k: null
            }
        }

        render() {
            return this.state.k
        }
    }

    class Act2 extends Act {

    }

    class App extends PureComponent<any, { act: ReactElement }> {
        constructor(props: any, context: any) {
            super(props, context)
            this.state = {
                act: null
            }
        }

        render() {
            return this.state.act;
        }
    }

    var app: App

    ReactDOM.render(<App ref={e => app = e}/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
    var act: Act
    let actE = <Act ref={(e) => {
        if (e) {
            act = e
        }
    }}/>
    app.setState({act: actE})
    act.setState({k: "v"})

    var act2: Act2
    var act2E = <Act2 ref={(e) => {
        if (e) {
            act2 = e
        }
    }}/>
    app.setState({act: act2E})
    act2.setState({k: "v2"})

    app.setState({act: actE})
```

Comment: Try adding an `useEffect(() => () => console.log('unmounted'), [])` to it. It is most likely being unmounted.

Comment: @windmaomao I actually tried something like this a while ago, gave up though for the exact same reason. I suggest you take a look at existing navigation libraries, and how they store the state. if you find out please let me know. I'm actually quite interested as well.

Comment: this seems like an interesting read: https://blog.atulr.com/react-custom-renderer-1/

Comment: I'm thinking creating a separate react container thingy for each screen. This is important as hooks and other stuff always need to be in the same order. And you most likely don't want to render the screens that are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I actually missed this line initially. So i thought you are managing
"hidden" components.

```
  return this.state.act;
```

But actually you are trying to mount `actE` and then `act2E` and then back to `actE`. ok. Your code essentially translate to something like this in a normal *React* code.

```
  const actE = <Act ref={ref} />, act2E = <Act ref={ref2} />
  return flag ? actE : act2E
```

After `actE` is unmounted, what happened to the stuff inside?

The problem is the following line.

```
    let actE = <Act ref={(e) => {
        if (e) {
            act = e
        }
    }}/>
```

You can't use a `if` here. Because if you do that, you miss the unmount. `act` in the above code is supposed to be `null` after unmount. And *React* want to make sure none of the internal is exposed anymore after that.

To be honest, you should wonder why your computer hasn't been frozen yet because your code should produce a memory leak ;)

Answer (score 0):

My tmp solution is cache reused reactElement's state and instance vars, when reuse reactElement, manually set the cache

following is my code:

```
    class Act extends PureComponent<any, { k: string }> {
        constructor(props: any, context: any) {
            super(props, context)
            this.state = {k: null}
        }

        k2: string

        render() {
            return `${this.state.k} ${this.k2}`
        }
    }

    class Act2 extends Act {
    }


    class App extends PureComponent<any, { act: ReactElement }> {
        constructor(p: any) {
            super(p)
            this.state = {act: null}
        }

        render() {
            return this.state.act
        }
    }

    var parentKeys = Object.keys(new PureComponent({}))

    var app: App

    var act: Act
    /**
     * reactElement is replace will be unmounted, for ex, my following code act2E instead actE, actE will be unmounted, if I wanna reuse actE, I should cache it's 'state' and instance vars
     * @param act
     */
    var getCache = (act: any) => {
        var keyVal: any = {}
        var keys = Object.keys(act).filter((e) => {
            return !parentKeys.includes(e)
        })
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            if (key != "state" && !key.match(/^_react/i)) { // should use special meth #setState to set, _react I don't need it
                keyVal[key] = act[key]
            }
        })
        return {keyVal: keyVal, state: act.state}
    }

    var setCache = (newAct: any, actCache: any) => {
        for (var [k, v] of Object.entries(actCache.keyVal)) {
            newAct[k] = v
        }

        act.setState(actCache.state)
        act.forceUpdate()
    }

    var actE = <Act ref={(e) => {
        act = e
    }}/>
    var act2: Act2
    var act2E = <Act2 ref={(e) => {
        act2 = e
    }}/>

    testReact(<App ref={e => app = e}/>)
    app.setState({act: actE})
    act.setState({k: "v"})
    act.k2 = "k2"
    var actCache = getCache(act)
    app.setState({act: act2E})
    act2.setState({k: "v2"})
    app.setState({act: actE})
    setCache(act, actCache)
```